# How to build regex to match values if they exists

Tags: regex

I have a requirement to match the complete string if some part of value exists or not

For example :- Here are the list of strings that should be matched

`en.key.value`
`fr.key.value`
`es.key.value`
`pt.key.value`
`key.value`

So, length of string before first `.` can only be >=2.

Below are some values which **should** not be accepted

`.key.value`
`z.key.value`

Could someone please help ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: A pattern like `(\w\w\)` matches exactly two characters. Thing is: you learn programming by TRYING things yourself first. Regular expressions are documented all over the places. There are literally hundreds of tutorials that explain you step by step how you use them. Thus: try yourself first, and only when you can't get your own idea to work for maybe hours ... then write up a [mcve] with your code here, and ask us to help with that. But please remember: you learn so much more when you do your first steps yourself, instead of *first* asking others to do the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[^.]{2,}\..+$
```

Matches

```
en.key.value
fr.key.value
es.key.value
pt.key.value
key.value
```

Does not match

```
.key.value
z.key.value
```

See yourself: [Regexr.com](https://regexr.com/6f8e0)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex : `/[a-z]{2,}\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/g`

`[a-z]{2,}` matches 2 or more repetitions of characters in the range between `a` and `z`.

`\.` matches the dot character.

`[a-z]+` matches 1 or more repetitions of characters between `a` and `z`.

```js
let regex = /[a-z]{2,}\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]+/g;

console.log(regex.test("fr.key.value"));
console.log(regex.test("z.key.value"));
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UFDJm1/1).

Comment: You can check it on https://regex101.com/ 
regex101 . com

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). You can split the string on the dots and check the length of the first part.

```java
String[] strings = {"en.key.value",
                    "fr.key.value",
                    "es.key.value",
                    "pt.key.value",
                    "key.value",
                    ".key.value",
                    "z.key.value"};
for (String string : strings) {
    String[] parts = string.split("\\.");
    System.out.printf("[%b] %s%n", (parts[0].length() >= 2), string);
}
```

Above code produces following output.

```
[true] en.key.value
[true] fr.key.value
[true] es.key.value
[true] pt.key.value
[true] key.value
[false] .key.value
[false] z.key.value
```

However, if you insist on using regular expressions, consider the following.

```java
String[] strings = {"en.key.value",
                    "fr.key.value",
                    "es.key.value",
                    "pt.key.value",
                    "key.value",
                    ".key.value",
                    "z.key.value"};
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-z]{2,}\\.");
for (String string : strings) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    System.out.printf("[%b] %s%n", matcher.find(), string);
}
```

Explanation of regular expression `^[a-z]{2,}\\.`

- `^` start of string
- `[a-z]` any lower-case letter of the English alphabet
- `{2,}` two or more occurrences of the preceding
- `\\.` literal dot

In other words, the above pattern matches strings that start with two or more lower-case characters followed by a single dot.